# Apache isis - Upgrading from 2.0.0-M5 to 2.0.0-M7

Tags: java, metamodel, isis

I changed my source code and pom.xml upgrading from 2.0.0-M5 to 2.0.0-M7.  Note, that none of the below errors were showing up in M5.  The application is compiling again but when going to the application, it shows a long list of metamodel validation error that weren't there in M5

This happens on a lot of classes.   Any clue as to how to properly fix this, (for the moment I get no further than commenting them out)?

```
someClass#defaultXSomeMethod(): is public, but orphaned (was not picked up by the framework); reporting orphans, because the class is setup for member introspection, without enforcing annotations
```

The following occurs on framework classes, and classes from libraries included that are not part of the domain model itself.   I have no clue what's going on nor how to fix this.

```
Collection action parameter found without supporting choices or autoComplete facet. Class: org.apache.isis.applib.query.Query action: withRange parameter 0
```

And then this one:

```
Action method overloading is not allowed, yet javax.activation.MimeType has action(s) that have a the same member name: [match]
```

this is an included library class, and it is used to parse the mimeType provided as an input parameter in one of the methods of a domain object.   It used to work in M5.  Any clue as to how to avoid this, or work around it?

Note, I also get the overloading error on my own DomainObjects (not in M5); I guess there the work around will be to stop overloading.

Thanks for any hints to point me in the right way

Comment: In 2.0.0-M6 and 2.0.0-M7 we made the programming model more sophisticated, but also made the metamodel validator more stringent.  Probably easiest for you to join the mailing list and from there we can invite you onto our slack channel to help you fix these issues.

Answer (score 0):

*"Collection action parameter found without supporting choices or autoComplete facet. Class: org.apache.isis.applib.query.Query action: withRange parameter 0"*

If this is a framework service then it shouldn't occur, and sounds like a bug.

I think the issue is in the `isis.core.meta-model.introspector. policy` configuration property - the default is to include non-annotated into the metamodel and - incorrectly - some types are being included that shouldn't be.

Alternatively, you can add either `@Programmatic` or `@Domain.Exclude` to ensure that methods are excluded from the metamodel.

As a workaround, try changing this config property.

Best though would be to join the users mailing list / slack channel so we can dig into the issue more thoroughly there.

Comment: Hi Dan, thx for replying.  I just joined the mailing list and asked to join the channel.   I will cross post on the mailing list then

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error, and realized I'd set the lombok annotation `@Getter` on my class instead of the field, so it was exposing getters for the injected services.
It was a bit cryptic because the stack trace didn't show the exact class that was affected.

Removing `@Getter` from the class level solved the problem.